# Как прочитать данные типа UInt8(Objective-C) в byte(Java)?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, byte

Извините, но я не знаю даже, как правильно вопрос задать.
Нужно сделать тестовое задание на языке `Java` для `Android`. Суть следующая. Есть закодированный файл `"File.TRK"`, этот файл состоит из списка нот, как мне сказали. Дали поля для ноты, но эти поля из `Objective-C`:

```
@property (nonatomic) Float64 timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic) UInt8 status;
@property (nonatomic) UInt8 notenum;
@property (nonatomic) UInt8 velocity;
@property (nonatomic) UInt8 trackN;
@property (nonatomic) Float32 duration;
@property (nonatomic) UInt16 scoreBits;
```

В своем проекте Java для модельки ноты я сделал такие поля с соответствующими геттерами и сеттерами:

```
private double timeStamp; //8 байт
private byte status;  //1 байт
private byte notenum;  //1 байт
private byte velocity;  //1 байт
private byte trackN;   //1 байт
private float duration;  //4 байта
private short scoreBits;  //2 байта
//суммарно каждая нота  = 18 байтам
```

Далее я получаю байты моего закодированного файла:

```
byte[] bytesFile = loadBytes("File.TRK");
private byte[] loadBytes(String s) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            InputStream stream = getAssets().open(s);
            try {
                bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("logs", "not load");
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

На этом моменте логи показывают, что длина моего массива `bytesFile` = 4752 (я так понимаю 4752/18 = 264 ноты. Т.е. мой закодированный файл состоит из 264 нот)
Далее методом `setNotes()` я заношу каждую ноту в ArrayList.

```
List<Note> notesFile = new ArrayList<>();
setNotes(bytesFile, notesFile);
private void setNotes(byte[] bytes, List<Note> list) {
        for (int a=0; a<bytesFile.length; a+=18){
            Note note = new Note();
            double myTimeStamp=ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes , a, a+8)).getDouble();
            float myDuration=ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes , a+12, a+16)).getFloat();
            short myScoreBits=ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes , a+16, a+18)).getShort();
            note.setTimeStamp(myTimeStamp);
            note.setStatus(bytes[a+8]);
            note.setNotenum(bytes[a+9]);
            note.setVelocity(bytes[a+10]);
            note.setTrackN(bytes[a+11]);
            note.setDuration(myDuration);
            note.setScoreBits(myScoreBits);
            list.add(note);
        }
    }
```

Логи показывают, что в списке нот содержится 264 ноты, все хорошо. Но затем, когда я в логах вывожу каждую ноту, то получаю вот такой результат (далее покажу первые 5 нот):

```
1 нота - timeStamp-1.469233414E-314, status-0, notenum-0, velocity-0, trackN-0, duration--32.75, scoreBits--25564
2 нота - timeStamp-2.052246093756482, status-0, notenum-0, velocity--100, trackN-38, duration-2.2061368E12, scoreBits-0
3 нота - -3.2944383806221925E-82, status-112, notenum-0, velocity-0, trackN-0, duration-4.725109E-13, scoreBits--25813
4 нота - 6.978446977931939E38, status-0, notenum-0, velocity--102, trackN-48, duration-2.006836, scoreBits-0
5 нота - 2.588782193414443E-183, status-107, notenum-0, velocity-0, trackN-0, duration--1.0570736E-28, scoreBits--25816
```

Для вывода ноты в логи я переопределил метод `toString()` в модельке ноты:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "timeStamp-"+getTimeStamp()+", status-"+getStatus()+", notenum-"+getNotenum()+", velocity-"+getVelocity()+
                ", trackN-"+getTrackN()+", duration-"+getDuration()+", scoreBits-"+getScoreBits();
    }
```

Суть моего задания в том, что мне нужно проиграть эту мелодию из нот. Но я не понимаю, почему в полях многих нот у меня встречаются отрицательные значения. Разве такое может быть? Все ли я делаю правильно? У меня вообще есть один из вариантов, что надо мной жестоко стебуться :) хеееелп, плиз!)

Comment: Добавьте код, который выводит ноты/переводит их в строки. Для удобоваримости хорошо бы еще почистить вопрос от шелухи: убрать ввод/вывод, оставить одно поле одной ноты и для него привести входные байты, ожидаемое и полученное значения. Код т.о. можно сократить до одного метода.

Comment: @defaultlocale Вы имеете ввиду, как я в логи вывожу мои ноты?

Comment: Да, если используется метод `toString` то и он.

Comment: @defaultlocale подправил свой вопрос. Внизу показано, как я в логи вывожу каждую ноту

Comment: @defaultlocale Что скажете?)

Comment: Стало лучше. Корень проблемы уже обозначил в своем ответе @ДмитрийНикифоров . Чтобы получить более точный ответ нужно указать конкретные значения: исходное (байт), полученное и желаемое. Еще, в вопросе 57 строк кода и только одна из них проблемная, попробуйте создать [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Для начала Вам нужно определиться с моделью, исходя из того, какие типы будут принимать методы воспроизведения. А уж после интерпритировать исходные данные в эти типы.

Answer (score 2):

`UInt8` -- беззнаковый тип (unsigned int), а `byte` в Java со знаком. Думаю, поэтому при побайтовом чтении у Вас получаются отрицательные числа.

Comment: Да, это я знаю, прочитал уже. Но и прочитал то, что нельзя просто взять число по модулю. Оно как-то иначе конвертируется и то, если конвертируется. Поэтому я пришел на стэковерфлоу, чтобы найти решение хоть какое-нибудь :)

Comment: Думаю, в таком случае лучше переформулировать вопрос как-нибудь так: "Как прочитать данные типа UInt8 в byte?".

Comment: Давайте переформулируем, я не против :) А вы решение знаете какое-нибудь?

Comment: Готового решения не знаю. Приходит в голову посмотреть, как устроено битовое представление в том и другом случаях, и понять, как переходить между ними с помощью побитовых операций. Вот здесь нечто похожее делается https://stackoverflow.com/a/7401635/8830684

Comment: В Java для представления отрицательных чисел используется дополнительный код (two's complement). Здесь можно посмотреть табличку соответствия битовых представлений и чисел знакового и беззнакового типов https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement . Похоже, что Вам нужно использовать метод `Byte.toUnsignedInt(b)`. Возможны два варианта: использовать его для прочитанного байта и сохранять положительное число в short или хранить (возможно, отрицательное) число в byte и использовать этот метод, когда вам нужно прочитать значение.

Comment: Дмитрий, я немного не понял вас. Если не затруднит, можете более подробно расписать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67647/discussion-between---and-yapv).

Answer (score 1):

Вам не должно быть разницы как это хранится в виде `signed byte` или `unsigned byte`. Если уж так хочется видеть на выдаче беззнаковые байтовые поля ноты, то надо сделать что-то типа:

```
private int byteToUnsignedInt(byte b) {
   return b & 0xFF;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "timeStamp-"+getTimeStamp()+", status-"+byteToUnsignedInt(getStatus())+", notenum-"+byteToUnsignedInt(getNotenum())+", velocity-"+byteToUnsignedInt(getVelocity())+
            ", trackN-"+byteToUnsignedInt(getTrackN())+", duration-"+getDuration()+", scoreBits-"+getScoreBits();
}
```

Тогда в выдаче вы увидите беззнаковые байты

Правда, что это вам даст? Вы знаете как их интерпретировать и что с ними надо делать проигрывателю ваших нот?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что значение поля `trackN` - это номер [ноты](http://pisali.ru/muzmart/36074/), `velocity` -вроде бы громкость звучания ноты. Эти поля как раз и обозначены UInt в модельке, которую мне дали, `timeStamp` - время входа ноты в мелодию, а `duration` - продолжительность ее звучания. Мне кажется все так. Допустим `velocity` у меня встречается в отрицательных значениях. Но такого же быть не может.

Comment: Вы не понимаете... есть байтовое значение допустим `0xfe` в виде signed byte это `-2`, а в виде unsigned byte это `+254`, но значение то ведь одно и то же `0xfe`... Это вы интерпретируете его как минус. То что я предлагаю вам - это представить его в смысле *unsigned byte*

Comment: Пригласите меня, пожалуйста, к вам в чат. Я не умею :)

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, я открыл мой закодированный файлик в hex редакторе. Значения полей `trackN` для первых 5 нот: 00, 26, 00, 30, 00 соответственно. Если сконвертировать в десятичное представление, то как раз и получается то, что показывают мои логи: 0, 38, 0, 48,0.  Я так понимаю это как раз и будет значение моих [нот](http://pisali.ru/muzmart/36074/)? Как думаете?